# How to translate a view and keep contextual filters?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I'm building a bilingual website (French/English). I created the "user biography" for me to display later in the view. The biography is translated.

The view is called in the page : biography.php?id_author=405 with a contextual filter (405 in this example). Now when we click to see the other language version, we are redirected to "biographie.php" (in french), but we lose the parameter.

How can i keep the parameter ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to "patch" the code, by adding the paramaters using Javascript.

```
 if($('.language-link').length > 0 && location.search != ""){
        $('.language-link').each(function(){
            var href = this.href;
            if (href.indexOf('?') != -1) {
                href = href + location.search;
              }
              else {
                href = href + location.search;
              }
              $(this).attr('href', href);
        });
    }
```